# how to fix pycocoevalcap.meteor unkown location

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, pycocotools

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/mnt/c/Users/smska/Desktop/research/wcl/main.py", line 7, in 
from modules.metrics import compute_scores
File "/mnt/c/Users/smska/Desktop/research/wcl/modules/metrics.py", line 2, in 
from pycocoevalcap.meteor import Meteor
ImportError: cannot import name 'Meteor' from 'pycocoevalcap.meteor' (unknown location)

how to fix this problem

Comment: provide a a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code that produces this error...